# Translation help, especially with "cum bello cupiendo"

Tags: translation-check, gerundive, gerund

I found the following translation exercise [online](http://users.ox.ac.uk/~univ2665/MILC/L_HT2.pdf):

> To say nothing of Philip, whom he rendered an enemy to the Romans,
>   though at a distance from him, Antiochus was the most powerful of all
>   kings at that period; and him he so inflamed with a desire for war,
>   that he endeavoured to bring troops against Italy even from the Red
>   Sea.

Here's what I came up with:

> De nihil dicendo Philippo, quem ipse inimicum Romanorum habebat
>   quamquam longinquum ab eo, Antiochus rex potentissimus erat saeculi
>   regibus omnibus illius: is cum bello cupiendo tam incensus ut conatus
>   esset copias de mari Rubro contra Italiam trahere.

Since the exercise concerns the use of gerunds and gerundives, I'm mostly concerned with the correctness of the phrase *cum bello cupiendo*. This was an attempt to apply a principle which the author expressed as follows:

> Latin prefers to attract the direct object into the case of the
>   gerund, which in turns adopts the gender and number of the object.

I'd like to verify that I understood it right.

Comment: When the gerundive enters the ablative case it seems to work either as a gerund or it just creates an agreement of case-endings. Here, "cum bello cupiendo tam incensus" = "so aroused with the war-desire/ blood-lust.". See Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/15243/1982.

Answer (score 4):

Your “translation exercise” is a famous (I thought) fragment from Nepos’ “Hannibal” (from *De exellentibus ducibus*, 2.1): “Nam ut omittam Philippum, quem absens hostem reddidit Romanis, omnium iis temporibus potentissimus rex Antiochus fuit. Hunc tanta cupiditate incendit bellandi, ut usque a rubro mari arma conatus sit inferre Italiae.”

[incendit = “he fired him up”; tantā cupiditate = “with so great a desire”; bellandi = “for waging war,” gen. gerundii with tantā cupiditate]

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's great that you found the original. Your answer might be even better if you also explained *tanta cupiditate incendit bellandi* a bit, and how/why it is different from the translation Expedito Bipdes chose.

Comment: incendit = “he fired him up”; tantā cupiditate = “with so great a desire”; bellandi = “for waging war” (gen. gerundii with tanta cupiditate)

Comment: Great, now, if you could put that in your answer somewhere?