# What Benefit is Conferred by the Inclusion of a Gerundive in an Ablative-Absolute (AA) Construction?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

In his answer to Q: [Can Gerundives be predicates of Ablative Absolutes?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/12724/1982), Seb offered a number of examples, the second of which:

"quo senatus consulto recitato cum [populus] more hoc insulso et novo plausum meo nomine recitando dedisset, habui contionem." (Cic. Att. 4.1.6) =

"With the recommendation of the Senate having been read out, when the people had applauded in this tasteless and new manner, with my name read out I spoke to the assembly."

Apart from the clumsy repetition of "recitato", why deploy a gerundive, in an ablative-absolute construction, ("meo nomine recitando"), as opposed to a conventional AA-construction, "meo nomine recitato" = "with my name (having been) read out"?

EDIT: 14/1/2021:

This is incorrect: "meo nomine recitato...habui contionem" has "my" (from "meo"), included in the AA, and "I" (in "habui") in the subsequent clause. This violates the grammatical rule that a species, in an AA, cannot be referred to again in the following clause.

Seb continued: "Hofman & Szantyr accept these examples only grudgingly as AAs, while gerundives are often and freely used in late Latin taking on the role of future-passive participles."

Is this example an AA, at all; or, simply an agreement of case-endings as directed by the grammatical rule governing gerundive constructions (noun/ pronoun must agree in case, number & gender with the gerundive)?

This would give: "meo nomine recitando" = "with my name (reading-out) calling....I spoke to the assembly.".

EDIT 11/1/2021:

In his answer to Q: [What is the difference in meaning/usage between "nasciturus" and "nascendus"?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/10679/1982), Mitomino offered an example of Cicero's use of the gerundive, in this way, which also demonstrates how the ablative case negates the gerundive's passive and deontic qualities:

"placet contra gaudere nosmet omittendis doloribus" (Cic. Fin. 1.56) =

"but on the other hand one is to rejoice by releasing pains".

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you asking in which cases the gerundive can be said to lack the passive and deontic (obligation) "qualities"/meanings? If so, perhaps you could try to formulate your question in a more transparent way. I agree with you that the two examples above (_meo nomine recitando_ & _omittendis doloribus_) can be said to be relevant to show the lack of those two meanings/"qualities" (passivity and obligation) that are present in examples like _Ceterum censeo Carthaginem esse delendam_.

Comment: @Mitomino: Thank you. In the first example, "meo nomine recitando", classed as a "borderline" ablative absolute (Hofman & Szantyr), how is the gerundive to be translated here? As yourself has shown, in the earlier Q., the ablative case negates the deontic & passive moods of this species. Therefore, must the gerundive, in this format, be translated as a gerund? If so, it must become a verbal noun; here, "the reading-out"/ "the calling"; giving "with 'the reading-out' of my name". In the second example, "the releasing"; giving "by the releasing of the pains".

Comment: @Mitomino: The problem with this approach is that a genitive will be required for the noun. Of course the grammatical rule, for the gerundive, demands the agreement of case-endings. Here, may be a clue to the answer: a gerundive, deployed in an ablative-absolute construction, will lose its passive & deontic moods but will to continue to dictate an agreement of case-endings. This beggars the question: why was such an agreement required? A guess: it suited the literary effect/ rhetorical force required by the speaker, here, Cicero.

Comment: @Mitomino: I asked why a conventional AA was not deployed e.g. "meo nomine recitato" = "with my name read-out"; overlooking that with "my" in the AA and "I" ("I spoke to the assembly") in the following clause, there would be a  violation of the grammatical rule governing the AA--a species in the AA must not appear again in the succeeding clause.

Comment: @Mitomino: The famous example from Cato uses indirect speech "I opine that... " (accusative-infinitive construction, "delendam esse") therefore the gerundive retains its natural qualities. The other example, previous Q., from yourself is trickier: "patriam ipsam inflammandam reliquimus"; "inflammandam" given as an accusative-gerundive, by Pinkster, having lost its deontic & passive properties, but only seems to work if translated as a gerund: "We have left our mother-city 'to the burning'".

Answer (score 1):

Has Cicero made a mistake?

In "meo nomine recitando...habui contionem" there is "my" (from "meo") in the AA, and "I" (in"habui") in the following clause.

This is a grammatical violation for the AA (see EDIT: 14/1/2021). That, or this is not an ablative absolute, contrary to the opinion of Hofman & Szantyr. Therefore, what can it be but an agreement of case-endings, dictated by the grammatical rule for the gerundive?

An example of this in my elementary text (Oulton):

"navibus eorum delendis hostes vicimus." =

"We conquered the enemy by destroying their ships."

This may look like an AA (ordinarily it would be "navibus deletis") but it isn't. If it was "eorum" (= "of these" [the enemy]) would be ablative-plural, "eis"--a grammatical violation because the enemy ("hostes") is referred to again, in the following clause.

Here, "navibus... delendis" is an agreement of case-endings dictated by the gerundive.

Similarly, in Mitomino's example (Comments in the 2nd. linked Q.) "omittendis doloribus" = "by releasing the pains".

EDIT: 15/1/2021:

This latter example is not an ablative-absolute either, as Mitomino has been good enough to remind me.

Concluding: there does not appear to be an advantage in the inclusion of a gerundive in an AA-construction. The gerundive, in the oblique cases, may lose its passive & deontic qualities but it will require an agreement of case-endings. This symmetry may have suited some Roman writers who used this technique e.g. Cicero.

***EDIT: 2/3/2021:

Thanks to Mitomino for a discussion on the well-known AA "mutatis mutandis" in Q: [On the alleged ambiguity of the Ablative Absolute "Mutatis mutandis"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/15476/1982) the accepted translation of which is:

> "with the things which ought to be changed (having been) changed".

This, more succinctly (Joonas in Q: [Why does the substantive come second in 'mutatis mutandis'?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5750/1982)

> "having changed what had to be changed".

Therefore, there is a role for the gerundive in an AA-construction in which the gerundive retains its deontic and passive qualities. However, as Mitomino indicates:

"... "mutandis" retains its passive and deontic meaning when it is the subject of the AA. However, it lacks these properties when it is the predicate e.g.

> "mutatis mutandis tribunatum gessit." =

> "He spent the tribunate in changing what had been changed."

Therefore, if "mutatis" is the subject it is "the things that were (having been) changed"; gerundive, "mutandis", the predicate, is "by changing"; giving:

> "by changing what had been changed" (Joonas)."

In "mutandis" = "by changing", it could be argued that the gerundive, in losing its deontic & passive qualities (in the ablative case) is functioning as a gerund ("by [the] changing") while continuing to dictate agreement in number, case and gender.

Both Mitomino & Joonas appear to agree that "mutatis mutandis" is ambiguous though there is some debate about when, in Roman history, each expression might have been accepted.

Comment: I agree that _navibus delendis hostes vicimus_ does not contain an AA. The 2nd example of gerundive construction is not an AA either but is a bit different since it is semantically selected by the verb _gaudere_: cf. _placet gaudere nosmet omittendis doloribus_ (Cic. _Fin_. 1.56). Note that the syntactic status of this 2nd gerundive is not different from the following "dominant participle" construction, which is also selected by the verb: _Cum absoluto Scaevola gauderet_,…’ (Cic. _Orat_. 2). Cf. http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.19:8:3:7.NewPerseusMonographs

Comment: @Mitomino: (Cic. de Oratore 2.281) "cum...valde absoluto Scaevola gauderet", the use of adjective-as-noun ("absoluto") gives "...when...with the acquitted one, Scaevola, Granius celebraed magnificently...". Is this correct? In English it woks better as an AA: "...when...with Scaevola [having been] acquitted, Granius celebrated magnificently...". Have you read Cerberus's answer to Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/110/1982? What an answer! Cerberus seems to agree that a gerundive does not really belong in an AA-construction; that it will, effectively, be translated as a gerund,

Comment: @Mitomino: as in "inflammandam", above. Example: "floribus carpendis Eurydice mordetur a serpente."